# Passing a jira object from django view method to another unique to that session

Tags: django, object, session, jira, jira-rest-api

All in the Django Views

I have a login method which takes the username/password and logs a user in using the python ldap method
Also the same credentials authenticate and make a jira object 
(Can be done as both are based on the same Active Directory)

in login method

```
def login(request):
    ....
    conn = ldap.initialize(....)
    conn.simple_bind_s(username, password) <-- user params
    jira = JIRA('server' , basic_auth=(username,password))
```

this jira object needs to be sent to a different view unique to that logged in session where that object has work done to it and avoids the user having to put in the creds again

I tried global variables but that isnt unique to the session

I tried Django's session variable

```
request.session['jira'] = jira
```

but i get a non serializable  error

How would i get this object from the login method to the desired view method